# Construct a bijection $h:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \{3,4\}^{\mathbb{P}}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have to construct a bijection $h:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \{3,4\}^{\mathbb{P}}$ where $\mathbb{P}=\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists k \in \mathbb{N} \ n=2k\}$. I came up with something like this: $$f:\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}\\g:\mathbb{P} \to \{3,4\}\\h(f)=g\\g(n)=f(n)+3$$Now I have to proof that $h(f)$ is a bijection. In order to do that, I need to proof that it is injective and surjective. The problem is I'm not sure how.

Comment: How are your functions $f,g$ defined? Also could you say more about how the desired bijection is defined, beyond what you have about composition?

Comment: What is gg? ? ?

Comment: @Tiamin $\mathbb{P}$ is not an advisable notation for the set of all even natural numbers, as it tends to be used to denote the set of all *prime* natural numbers. A very straightforward way to refer to the set of all even naturals is $2\mathbb{N}$, no need to introduce new characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having a mental block of functions being "points" as space and conceiving of a function that maps the set functions to another set of functions.  I had the same block when I was a student.

If $f\in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ then that means $f$ is function $f:\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$ so that for any $n\in \mathbb N$ then $f(n) =\begin{cases}0\\1\end{cases}$.

(  There are, of course, an infinite number such function elements of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$.  In fact, if we define $a_n := f(n)$ then $\{f(1),f(2),f(3),.....\} = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ could be any infinite sequence of $0,1$ terms and we can define the elements of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ by considering any such sequence $\{b_k\}$ so that $h(n) := b_n$ and therefore $h\in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$.)

And the same is true for $\{3,4\}^{\mathbb P}$.  If $h\in \{3,4\}^{\mathbb P}$ then $g:\mathbb P\to \{3,4\}$ and for any $m=2k\in \in \mathbb P$ then $h(m)=\begin{cases}3\\4\end{cases}$.

Now it should be intuitive that this are equivalent.  For every $f \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ so that $f: n\mapsto \begin{cases}0\\1\end{cases}$ we can just make a $g:\mathbb P \to \{3,4\}$ via $g: 2n \mapsto \begin{cases}3&\text{if }f(n)=0\\4&\text{if }f(n)=1\end{cases}$

So.... lets do that:  Consider $\tau:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\to \{3,4\}^{\mathbb P}$ via $\tau{f} = g$ where $g: \mathbb P\to \{3,4\}$ via $g(2n)=\begin{cases}3&\text{if }f(n)=0\\4&\text{if }f(n)=1\end{cases}$.

Now we have to prove

1. $\tau$ is a well-defined function.
2. $\tau$ is onto
3. $\tau$ is one to one

Proving 1: for any $f\in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ will be a well defined function the maps any $k\in \mathbb N$ to a distinct value of either $0$ or $1$.  For ever $p\in \mathbb P$ there is a unique $m\in \mathbb N$ so that $p = 2m$.  For that distinct $m$ there is a distinct value of $0$ or $1$ and for that distinct value we can assign $p \mapsto 3$ if $f(m)=0$ or $p\mapsto 4$ if $f(m)=1$.  As there is no ambiguity in this mapping and each element $p$ is mapped to a distinct element of $\{3,4\}$ this mapping is a function mapping $\mathbb P \to \{3,4\}$ and is an element of $\{3,4\}^{\mathbb P}$.  So $\tau$ is well defined.

Proving 2:  If $g:\mathbb P \to \{3,4\}$ we can define $f:\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$ via $f(n) = \begin{cases}0&\text{if }g(2n)=3\\1&\text{if }g(2n)=4\end{cases}$.  Then $\tau(f)(p)=\begin{cases}3&\text{if }f(\frac p2)=0\\4&\text{if }f(\frac p2)=1\end{cases}=\begin{cases}3&\text{if }g(2\cdot\frac p2)=3\\4&\text{if }g(\frac 2\cdot \frac p2)=4\end{cases}=g(n)$.  So $\tau(f)= g$.

Proving 3:

Suppose $f,h \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ but $f\ne h$.  That means there is a $k\in \mathbb N$ where $f(k) \ne h(k)$.  If $f(k) = 0$ then $h(k) = 1$ and therefore $\tau(f)(2k) = 3$ while $\tau(h)(2k) = 4$.  And if $f(k) =1$ then $h(k) = 0$ and therefore $\tau(f)(2k) = 4$ while $\tau(h)(2k) =3$.

In either case if $f \ne h$ then $\tau(f) \ne \tau(h)$.

So $\tau$ is one-to-one.